# Convert Excel nested function into R code

Tags: r

Kindly help convert the Excel Nested function into R code
`IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Unknown",D1134)),1,if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("<1",D1134)),2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1-4",D1134)),3,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("5-9",D1134)),4,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("10-14",D1134)),5,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("15-19",D1134)),6,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("20-24",D1134)),7,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("25-29",D1134)),8,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("30-34",D1134)),9,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("35-39",D1134)),10,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("40-44",D1134)),11,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("45-49",D1134)),12,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("50+",D1134)),13,"")))))))))))))`

Comment: I think you just need `factor`.

Comment: @zx8754 What would the full code be like using `factor`

Comment: try `as.integer(factor(D1134))`

Comment: `myData$newColumn <- factor(myData$oldColumn, levels = c("<1", "1-4", ... "50+"))` Read the manuals please.

Comment: @zx8754 I have tried your example but it's not working. It is not putting the values of 1,2,3 ....13 in the newColumn

Comment: The above excel function is trying to search for a pattern, if found places a value in that cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `dplyr::case_when` here. I'll assuming that you have a vector `vec` which might be by itself or may be a column of a frame (in which case this is likely in a dplyr pipe or similar, over to you).

```r
library(dplyr)
ptns <- c("Unknown", "<1", "5-9", "10-40")
mydata <- data.frame(vec = c("Unknown results", "The team won 10-40", "My height in feet is between 5-9", "IDK"))
mydata %>%
  mutate(newcol = case_when(
    grepl("Unknown", vec, fixed = TRUE) ~ 1L, 
    grepl("<1", vec, fixed = TRUE) ~ 2L, 
    grepl("5-9", vec, fixed = TRUE) ~ 3L, 
    grepl("10-40", vec, fixed = TRUE) ~ 4L, 
    TRUE ~ -1L)
  )
#                                vec newcol
# 1                  Unknown results      1
# 2               The team won 10-40      4
# 3 My height in feet is between 5-9      3
# 4                              IDK     -1
```

An alternative is if you have a vector of patterns and just care about the first match.

```r
mydata %>%
  mutate(
    newcol = apply(sapply(c(ptns, ""), grepl, x = vec), 1, which.max),
    newcol = if_else(newcol > length(ptns), NA_integer_, newcol)
  )
#                                vec newcol
# 1                  Unknown results      1
# 2               The team won 10-40      4
# 3 My height in feet is between 5-9      3
# 4                              IDK     NA
```

Comment: How do I assign this to a new column

Comment: `mydata %>% mutate(newcol = case_when(...))`. It would be easier to help if you provided more context, including sample data.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. It has worked. I have managed to assign to a new column using mutate using an example from Google search

Comment: See my edit, @FredKwebiha, another option if you're interested (with working code and sample data, no less).

Comment: The first option worked for me